# We want to model events and staff (contacts) such that we can store prep hours for each staff member at the event

Tags: related-list, activities, junction-object

We have created a custom object to store the hours, but it seems that the ability to related Activities (Events in this case) to custom objects is limited or disabled. We are willing to write custom code but are somewhat novices and would appreciate some pointers. 
TIA

Comment: You're right; you can't link any object to an Event, although an Event can be linked to pretty much any object. You might have better luck creating a custom Event object, and linking them together through some trigger logic.

Comment: Are your Events related to Opportunity or some other object? If so, approaching the solution from that end is the way you'll want to solve the problem you're having.

Comment: They are not related to Opportunities, but can add that level if it would help to solve the problem. We are at the beginning of development cycle and so can try different approaches. If the staff member were modeled as an opportunity, then the 'prep hours' field could be an opportunity field as long as each event can have multiple opportunities. Thanks again for the replies.